# Get list of all files in a azure data lake directory to a look up activity in ADFV2

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-pipelines, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have a number of files in azure data lake storage, i am creating a pipeline in ADFV2 to get the list of all the files in a folder in ADLS. How to do this?

Comment: Hi,any progress?If you think my answer helps you,you could mark it for answer,thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @JayGong i was looking for any activity which can do this, with get metadata activity i was able to do this in pipeline.

Comment: Sure,I get it. So,you already marked DraganB's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Get metadata activity. 
Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You could follow below steps to list files in ADLS.

1: Use ADLS SDK to get the list file names in a specific directory and output the results. Such as Java SDK [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk#list-directory-contents). Of course, you could use .net or Python.

```
// list directory contents
List<DirectoryEntry> list = client.enumerateDirectory("/a/b", 2000);
System.out.println("Directory listing for directory /a/b:");
for (DirectoryEntry entry : list) {
    printDirectoryInfo(entry);
}
System.out.println("Directory contents listed.");
```

2. Compile the file so that it could be executed.Store it into azure blob storage.

3.Use custom activity in azure data factory to configure the blob storage path and execute the program. More details,please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity).

You could use custom activity in Azure data factory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk#list-directory-contents